# I don't understand one liner if else statement in javascript. Can anyone explain?

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement, web

I was reading this code:

```
enter code here

table.onclick = function(event) {
  let td = event.target.closest('td');
  **if (!td) return;
  if (!table.contains(td)) return;**
  detail(td); 
};
```

But i dont undestand why there is no Curly braces in if statement. Why there is no else part. Also I dont know what the return means in one line if statement. What does this code mean.

Comment: If you only have one line of code in a "block" you don't need the curly braces, only when it's an actual block of code. Else is never required, that's only to catch all other cases, in case that is required.

Comment: Just for the future - those ** bold stars confuse your question